# Tic Tac Toe - Turns C

Tags: c, loops

I've been turning around and around trying to figure out how to give my players turns. The questions is for there to be two players playing tic tac toe but I can't figure how to do that. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void displayBoard(char [3][3]);enter code here
int playerType (int player, char boardArray[3][3]);
int selectLocation(char [3][3], int , int );
char setTurn(char [3][3], int , int , char );


int main()
{
    int player,location;
    char position;
    char boardArray[3][3]={{'1','2','3'},
            {'4','5','6'},
            {'7','8','9'}};

    player= playerType (player, boardArray);

    int i;

    for(i=0;i<9;i++)
    {

        if (player==3)
            break;
        else{

            location=selectLocation(boardArray, player, location);

            position=setTurn(boardArray, location, player, position);
        }

    }


    return 0;
}

void displayBoard(char boardArray [3][3]) //This displays the tic tac toe board
{
    printf("\t%c|%c|%c\n", boardArray[0][0], boardArray[0][1], boardArray[0][2]);
    printf("\t%c|%c|%c\n", boardArray[1][0], boardArray[1][1], boardArray[1][2]);
    printf("\t%c|%c|%c\n", boardArray[2][0], boardArray[2][1], boardArray[2][2]);

}
int playerType (int player, char boardArray [3][3]) //This decides who plays first
{

    player=0;

    printf("Enter 1 for Player X.\n");
    printf("Enter 2 for Player O.\n");
    printf("Enter 3 to Quit. \n");
    scanf("%d", &player);


    if (player == 1)
    {
        printf("You're player X.\n");
        displayBoard(boardArray);
    }
    else if (player == 2)
    {
        printf("You're player O.\n");
        displayBoard(boardArray);
    }
    else if(player == 3)
        printf("You Quit.\n");

    else
        printf("Invalid Entry.\n");




    return player;
}


int selectLocation(char boardArray[3][3], int player, int location) //This takes in the location
{
    printf("Pick a location from 1-9.\n");
    scanf("%d", &location);

    return location;
}

char setTurn(char boardArray[3][3], int location, int player, char position) //This outputs the location
{

    if (player == 1)
    {
        switch(location)
        {
        case 1:
        {
            boardArray[0][0]='x';
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            boardArray[0][1]='x';
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            boardArray[0][2]='x';
            break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            boardArray[1][0]='x';
            break;
        }
        case 5:
        {
            boardArray[1][1]='x';
            break;
        }
        case 6:
        {
            boardArray[1][2]='x';
            break;
        }
        case 7:
        {
            boardArray[2][0]='x';
            break;
        }
        case 8:
        {
            boardArray[2][1]='x';
            break;
        }
        case 9:
        {
            boardArray[2][2]='x';
            break;
        }
        default:
            printf("invalid");
        }

    }
    else if (player == 2)
    {
        switch(location)
        {
        case 1:
        {
            boardArray[0][0]='O';
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            boardArray[0][1]='O';
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            boardArray[0][2]='O';
            break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            boardArray[1][0]='O';
            break;
        }
        case 5:
        {
            boardArray[1][1]='O';
            break;
        }
        case 6:
        {
            boardArray[1][2]='O';
            break;
        }
        case 7:
        {
            boardArray[2][0]='O';
            break;
        }
        case 8:
        {
            boardArray[2][1]='O';
            break;
        }
        case 9:
        {
            boardArray[2][2]='O';
            break;
        }
        default:
            printf("Invalid");
        }
    }

    printf("\t%c|%c|%c\n", boardArray[0][0], boardArray[0][1], boardArray[0][2]);
    printf("\t%c|%c|%c\n", boardArray[1][0], boardArray[1][1], boardArray[1][2]);
    printf("\t%c|%c|%c\n", boardArray[2][0], boardArray[2][1], boardArray[2][2]);


    return position;

}
```

Comment: So...like where are you stuck? What is expected o/p and what is actual?

Comment: I would rather initialize the boardArray to all 0's and make the boardindex to 1 or 2 to indicate which players owns the index. but returning to your question ... this seems unclear .. which function of your switch turns ? or turn function is still to be created ?

Comment: Turn functions is still to be created. I was thinking maybe I will have a nested for loop, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Change `player selection` part `player= playerType (player, boardArray);` inside `for` loop like this -

```
int player,location;
char position;
char boardArray[3][3]={{'1','2','3'},
                       {'4','5','6'},
                       {'7','8','9'}};
int i;
for(i=0;i<9;i++)
{
    player= playerType (player, boardArray);
    if (player==3)
        break;
    else
    {
        location=selectLocation(boardArray, player, location);
        position=setTurn(boardArray, location, player, position);
    }
}
```